# seeds.rb rails db:seed not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have the following in my seeds.rb file:

```
pop_culture = Category.create(category_name: 'Pop Culture')
sports = Category.create(category_name: 'Sports')
tazos = Category.create(category_name: 'Tazos')
woolworths = Category.create(category_name: 'Woolworths')
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'AFL', category: sports)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'NRL', category: sports)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Basketball', category: sports)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Baseball', category: sports)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Cricket', category: sports)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Ninja Turtles', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Pokemon', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Final Fantasy', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Marvel Cards', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'DC', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Yu-gi-oh', category: pop_culture)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Looney Tunes', category: tazos)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Cheetahs', category: tazos)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Star Wars', category: tazos)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Simpsons', category: tazos)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Space Jam', category: tazos)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Dreamworks', category: woolworths)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Disney Dominoes', category: woolworths)
Subcategory.create(subcategory_name: 'Marvel Discs', category: woolworths)
```

and when I run the `db:seed` in my terminal it throws an error:

> rails aborted! ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown
>   attribute `category_id`
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:182:in
>   `with_value_from_database'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:53:in`write_from_user'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:50:in
>   `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:32:in`
>   write_attribute'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:361:in
>   `[]='
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:76:in`
>   replace_keys'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:14:in
>   `replace'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:22:in`
>   writer'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:119:in
>   `category='
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in`
>   public_send'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:46:in
>   `_assign_attribute'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:40:in`
>   block in _assign_attributes'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in
>   `each'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:39:in`
>   _assign_attributes'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in
>   `_assign_attributes'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in`
>   assign_attributes'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:319:in
>   `initialize'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in`
>   new'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in
>   `new'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in`
>   create' /home/vic/railsapps/Swap_Deck/db/seeds.rb:12:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in`load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in`load_dependency'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:549:in`
>   load_seed'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:268:in
>   `load_seed'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:196:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in
>   `block in run_rake_task'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in`
>   run_rake_task'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in
>   `run_command!'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`
>   ' /home/vic/railsapps/Swap_Deck/bin/rails:9:in
>   `require' /home/vic/railsapps/Swap_Deck/bin/rails:9:in`'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   call'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in
>   `call'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`
>   load'
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in
>   `<top (required)>' /home/vic/railsapps/Swap_Deck/bin/spring:15:in`
>   ' bin/rails:3:in `load' bin/rails:3:in`'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:seed (See full trace by running task with --trace)

So, is there something I need to fix? I can get it to seed just the categories and that works, but I need the subcategories as well, as I want them for a drop-down on my site.

I've been trying to get this stupid thing to work for ages, but I can't get my head around the whole category/subcategory thing.

The migrations code for categories and subcats:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.string :category_name
      t.references :subcategory_id, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subcategories do |t|
      t.integer :subcategory_id
      t.string :subcategory_name
      t.references :category_id, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Error say that Subcategory model does not have category_id column. Is it true? May you show structure and models code for Category and Subcategory

Comment: my models are as follows:class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
and:class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
end

Comment: Does my answer resolved the issue?

Comment: No, there were a whole bunch of other issues that came up. So I had to get help from some of my real life helpers as I said below.

Answer (score 0):

> rails aborted! ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown
>   attribute category_id

The error tells that you are missing `category_id` attribute in `subcategories` table. make sure you have that to fix the error.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in my migrations it says there's a category_id: class CreateSubcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subcategories do |t|
      # t.integer :subcategory_id
      t.string :subcategory_name
      t.references :category_id, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: @VicAlfieri Does the subcategories table in DB has `category_id` as well?

Comment: @VicAlfieri the migration code has comment sign `#` in the beginning of string with `category_id` column `# t.integer :subcategory_id`. May be because of this you don't have `category_id` in your database table.

Comment: @IlyaLavrov Only the line `t.integer :subcategory_id` is commented out as I can see.

Comment: @VicAlfieri Can you update the question with the migration file code?

Comment: @Pavan i added it to the question :)

Comment: @VicAlfieri Have you run `rake db:migrate`? Also does the `category_id` exists in the `subcategories` table in DB?

Comment: I have done a db:migrate on just the categories, and a db:seed, these do work on the categories by themselves, but adding the subcats is what's giving me grief

Comment: @VicAlfieri You should do db:migrate on subcategories as well!

Comment: db:migrate doesn't run on all the migrations? do I need to run migrations on all the things>?

Comment: @VicAlfieri It depends on when you run. If you run db:migrate defore creating migration file for subcategories, then the subcategories wont't be migrated unless you do db:migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your seeds I assume that a category can have multiple subcategories.

In this case your migrations should be:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :category_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateSubcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subcategories do |t|
      t.string :subcategory_name
      t.references :category, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You do not need to specify category_id and subcategory_id as the migrations will automatically generate a primary key column named id.

Full details of how to use migrations are specified [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

and your models should be:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

In addition I suggest you rename the category_name to name and subcategory_name to name. The use of prefix is redundant.

Comment: This issue has now been solved with help from some handy people in real life. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines before the migrations inside the `seeds.rb` file

```rb
Category.reset_column_information
Subcategory.reset_column_information
```